# OpenCV undefined reference to `vtable for cv::HOGDescriptor'

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I'm trying to compile my own object detector by using OpenCV 3 hog and svm over Eclipse CDT but when compiling the console returns the following:

```
Building target: HogDetection
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "HogDetection"  ./main.o ./phog.o ./psvm.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml
./phog.o: In function `cv::HOGDescriptor::HOGDescriptor()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/objdetect.hpp:348: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::HOGDescriptor'
./phog.o: In function `cv::HOGDescriptor::~HOGDescriptor()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/objdetect.hpp:372: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::HOGDescriptor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [HogDetection] Error 1
```

Probably I'm doing something wrong with the libraries but since I'm new both to c++ and OpenCV I followed a tutorial to set up eclipse CDT with openCV and I was able to run other simple tutorials (those on openCV websites like display image and so on...).

I also read something on wikipedia about vtable and here but it was not sufficient for me to understand what's happening here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: similar error solved here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955972/problems-using-hogdescriptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955972/problems-using-hogdescriptor).

Comment: @MisterC your answer solved my problem, I just add opencv_objdetect to the linker.

Comment: @zenith thanks for your usefull answer but it is too general for a noob like me. It will help me in improving my knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by adding to the gcc c++ linker libraries the library `opencv_objdetect`

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are working with make files then just add
LIBS += -L/usr/local/libs \
         -**lopencv_objdetect** \

or if you are not having makefile then just run code like
**g++ -Wall main.cpp /usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.a -o main**